# how to get the home addresses of all contacts in the iphone address book

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i am developing an application, but now i stuck at this point (that how to get the street,zip,state,country) of all the contacts in the iphone address book. Any sample code will be very helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get address for all contacts as -

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();

NSArray *contactArr = (NSArray *)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);

for (int i = 0; i < [contactArr count]; i++) 
{
    ABRecordRef person = (ABRecordRef)[contactArr objectAtIndex:i];

    ABMultiValueRef address = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonAddressProperty);

    for(CFIndex j = 0; j < ABMultiValueGetCount(address); j++)
    {
        CFDictionaryRef addressDict = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(address, j);

        CFStringRef streetValue = CFDictionaryGetValue(addressDict, kABPersonAddressStreetKey);

        CFStringRef cityValue = CFDictionaryGetValue(addressDict, kABPersonAddressCityKey);

        CFStringRef stateValue = CFDictionaryGetValue(addressDict, kABPersonAddressStateKey);

        CFStringRef zipValue = CFDictionaryGetValue(addressDict, kABPersonAddressZIPKey);

        CFStringRef countryValue = CFDictionaryGetValue(addressDict, kABPersonAddressCountryKey);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old but here is a edited version which is based on the answer of saadnib. It follows ARC and respect the authorization status. 
The method returns a NSMutableDictionary which contains the name of the person together with one or more addresses (connected trough the ID).

```
- (NSMutableDictionary *)MyGetAddressesAndNamesOfContacts
{
    if (ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() == kABAuthorizationStatusDenied)
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No permission" message:@"This App has no permission to access your contacts." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];

        return nil;
    }

    if (ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() == kABAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined)
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Why this App needs your contacts" message:@"In the following your device will ask you whether this App is allowed to access your contacts. This is recommented because..." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"I understand" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];
    }

    ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();      // deprecated since iOS 6
    NSArray *contactArr = (NSArray *)CFBridgingRelease(ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook));
    NSMutableDictionary *dPersons = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    for (int i = 0; i < [contactArr count]; i++)
    {
        ABRecordRef person = (ABRecordRef)CFBridgingRetain([contactArr objectAtIndex:i]);
        NSString *firstName = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
        NSString *lastName = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty);
        NSString *sPersonName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", firstName, lastName];

        ABMultiValueRef address = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonAddressProperty);
        NSString *sAddress;

        for(CFIndex j = 0; j < ABMultiValueGetCount(address); j++)
        {
            CFDictionaryRef addressDict = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(address, j);

            CFStringRef streetValue = CFDictionaryGetValue(addressDict, kABPersonAddressStreetKey);
            CFStringRef cityValue = CFDictionaryGetValue(addressDict, kABPersonAddressCityKey);
            CFStringRef stateValue = CFDictionaryGetValue(addressDict, kABPersonAddressStateKey);
            CFStringRef zipValue = CFDictionaryGetValue(addressDict, kABPersonAddressZIPKey);
            CFStringRef countryValue = CFDictionaryGetValue(addressDict, kABPersonAddressCountryKey);

            sAddress = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@, %@", streetValue, cityValue, countryValue];
        [dPersons setObject:sAddress forKey: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d %@%ld", @"AddressFromNameID", i, @"Number", j]];
        }

        [dPersons setObject:sPersonName forKey: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d", @"NameWithID", i]];
    }

    return dPersons;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   NSArray *addresses = (NSArray*)[contact.postalAddresses valueForKey:@"value"];

        if (!(addresses == nil) && addresses.count > 0)
        {

            for (CNLabeledValue<CNPostalAddress*>* labeledValue in contact.postalAddresses)
            {

                NSString *city = labeledValue.value.city;
                NSLog(@"City = %@",city);

                NSString *street = labeledValue.value.street;
                NSLog(@"Street = %@",street);

                NSString *state = labeledValue.value.state;
                NSLog(@"State = %@",state);

                NSString *postalCode = labeledValue.value.postalCode;
                NSLog(@"PostalCode = %@",postalCode);

                NSString *ISOCountryCode = labeledValue.value.ISOCountryCode;
                NSLog(@"ISOCountryCode = %@",ISOCountryCode);

            }
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"No addresses for name = %@",strname);
        }
```

Comment: This gives Postal addresses individual field values using contacts framework.